# Arabic language issue in ms sql 2014 and IBM Control Desk 7.6.1

Tags: sql-server, websphere, sql-server-2014, maximo

I have finished the install IBM Control Desk 7.6.1 on database MS SQL 2014 
I have selected in the installation wizard language English and Arabic
when I select Arabic in the login page I found all Arabic words like  ?????
I already added "&charset=windows-1256" in maximo.properties
when I insert or update value directly in the database with Arabic characters it converts to question marks like 
عربي I found it ؟؟؟؟ 
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Looks like a `varchar` *somewhere*, or the wrong collation. Where, is a very different question, and we don't have the information to tell you.

Comment: Yes Larnu 
I have varchar columns like 'description' is varchar (200)

Comment: Well there's your problem. You can't store unicode characters in a `varchar`.

Comment: maybe yes but I have an issue in the database with IBM Control desk

Comment: Well, yes... `DECLARE @MyVariable varchar(200) = N'عربي'; SELECT @MyVariable;` is going to return `'????'`. You need to change the data type of your column.

Comment: Ok, sir, it is good but my issue in the whole of the database

Comment: If you need to store Arabic characters, then you need to ensure every column that could store those characters is an `nvarchar`; that means changing the datatype of all of them. I'm afraid, however, that any data that has already been inserted has already been lost though.

Comment: Not sure you can have Arabic and English on the same instance. Here's what IBM says about Maximo which is built on the same software foundation :
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLKT6_7.6.1/com.ibm.mam.inswl.doc/install/t_ccmdb_manconfigdbsqlserver.html

Comment: @HussinMhmode Did you look at this one? Same issue as yours. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42261350/maximo-7-6-sql-server-2014-chinese-or-thai-characters

Comment: **The issue was solved** Thank you for everyone help me, Here's what I have learned to solve the problem**حل مشكلة ظهور الحروف العربية على شكل علامات استفهام في SQL Server**  [https://www.mobarmijoun.com/2014/05/sql-server.html] and **Manually configuring Microsoft SQL Server 2012**[https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLKT6_7.6.1/com.ibm.mam.inswl.doc/install/t_ccmdb_manconfigdbsqlserver.html]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was solved Thank you for everyone help me

1. حل مشكلة ظهور الحروف العربية على شكل علامات استفهام في SQL Server
   https://www.mobarmijoun.com/2014/05/sql-server.html
2. Manually configuring Microsoft SQL Server 2012
   https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLKT6_7.6.1/com.ibm.mam.inswl.doc/install/t_ccmdb_manconfigdbsqlserver.html